# how to separate the ui and implementation in PyQT?

Tags: python, user-interface, inheritance, pyqt, pyside

I have a question while i am trying to separate the ui and the implementation files.
I used QT creator to create *.ui, then converted it to *.py

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 
from myUI import Ui_Form
import sys

class Prog(Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__();

def main():
    Program =  QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv);
    MyProg=Prog();
    MyProg.show();
    Program.exec_();

if __name__=='__main__':
    main();
```

**myUI.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__();
        self.setupUi();
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 230, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 250, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 80, 104, 87))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))
```

My Questions are

1. I got the error msg as follows.

   **self.setupUi();
   TypeError: setupUi() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Form'**

   But if i change **self.setupUi();**  into  **self.setupUi(self);** in myUI.py

   it works.   I am wondering why **self** has to be invoked in **self.setui()**
2. In myUI.py, Why there is **def setupUi(self, Form):**, not **def setupUi(self):**

   I know that is because we treated Form as a variable, and will use it later on. But, why we need it? or can we create a member as **self.Form** instead of invoking **Form**

THX!

Comment: Please see the [pyuic5 documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code) for how to use the converted ui files.

Comment: so the better idea is to declare a ui class member? but in the document, it also provided the examples with inheritance from UI class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's **not** a good idea to change the UI file as it will be regenerated every time you update the UI in Qt Creator and any changes will be lost.

Instead, make another UI class that calls the auto generated file for you (and there are other designs for defining the UI class, as ekhumoro pointed out):

```
class Prog(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__();
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__=='__main__':
    Program =  QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MyProg = Prog()
    MyProg.show()
    sys.exit(Program.exec_())
```

In this way, an instance of the class `Prog` is passed into the `setupUi` method (`self` is the reference the `Prog` instance has to itself). Within the `setupUi` method this reference is called `Form`, and is used many times, as can be seen in your code:

```
Form.resize(400, 300)
self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
```

`Form` is named such probably because you set `objectName` to be `Form` in Qt Creator. However, regardless of what it's called this is a reference to the parent widget that the auto generated file needs to setup. Conceptually it would make more sense if you named them the same, e.g. rename both your `Prog` class and the UI `objectName` to something like `ProgramUI`.

Comment: you partially answered my question.  But why we need "Form" here?
for variable, unless we declare it, we cannot use it. It looks like "Form" comes for no reason (no declaration), but we need it. Does Form is kinda conservative word in QT?